# ECG/EKG software language advice

Tags: c#, java, c++, python, c

Simply, I'm developing a wireless ECG (electrocardiogram, or EKG from the German Elektrokardiogramm) and I need to choose the best language for a desktop application that allows the following:

- wireless transmission of data over WiFi
- real-time graphing of ECG data signal
- a good DSP library

Thanks.

Comment: given its mission critical nature, I'm not even sure this is the place to ask this question

Comment: I've done it with with C# and Python; I know others who've done it in C and C++. I'm not sure what you mean by "large amounts of data", though -- a 12-lead ECG at 1kHz, 16 bits per sample is under 200kbps. That's not very much.

Comment: It depends of the architecture of your application, is it a wireless sensor that is sending data out via WiFi to another device (PC, server, tablet, smartphone)?

Answer (score 1):

From the viewpoint of a normal program (i.e., not a device driver) a Wi-Fi connection is just a network connection -- not noticeably different from (for example) a wired Ethernet connection.

Real-time graphing and digital signal processing libraries are probably a *little* less common, but not much. "Real time" is one of those slippery phrases that it's hard to pin down exactly what it means (different people use it differently). At a guess, you just mean you want to update the graph as data arrives. In that case, the important question is what bandwidth you're dealing with -- i.e., how many updates of how much information, how fast?

Bottom line -- none of what you've told us gives much in the way of real criteria for picking a language to use. The obvious open question would be performance -- how much data you need to process, and how much processing you need to do on it. That might at least hint at one being better than another.

Comment: 160 - 200 kbps is what I'm going to be sending.

Comment: @patrick: at that rate, pretty much any of the above should be fine on a modern machine unless you need to do really heavy-duty processing.

Comment: Your UI code will likely be larger and more complex than the signal processing - I suspect that that will influence your language choice more than signal processing and comms (which works well in pretty much any modern language.)